# nm-applet thinks I'm offline

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-12.04, networkmanager, wicd

I got on wireless with `wicd-curses`, but `nm-applet` thinks I'm disconnected.

What I'm really trying to do is get on my VPN, and I usually do this through `nm-applet`. It doesn't want to let me on VPN since it thinks I'm offline.

Comment: you can always start your connection to your VPN by hand...

Comment: @MariusMatutiae How?

Comment: Depends on type of VPN

Comment: Well, it looks with `nm-tool` like the problem is that `iwlwifi` seems "unavailable".

Comment: Of course it does: it is being controlled by a different program with the same scope. You may use either wicd or nm, nt both. BTW, ring or group isomorphisms?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I made the name in reference to http://delong.typepad.com/sdj/2008/02/cosma-shalizi-c.html

Comment: @MariusMatutiae As far as what maths I'm into right now, http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2005-42-02/S0273-0979-05-01053-0/S0273-0979-05-01053-0.pdf and http://ncatlab.org/timporter/show/crossed+menagerie are both pretty cool, as is http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3255

Comment: @MariusMatutiae From http://superuser.com/questions/556239/using-a-vpn-with-wicd it looks like I can't `wicd` to a VPN.